# Help with a sequences proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Sorry for the annoyance but I have a proof to do which I don't find.
I have $$
\begin{cases}
u_0 = 0 \\
v_0 = 0
\end{cases} \\ \text{and}
\begin{cases}
u_{n+1} = \sqrt{3-v_n} \\
v_{n+1} = \sqrt{3+u_n}
\end{cases}
$$
I first had to show that these sequences are well defined which I did by showing first we have for all $n \in \mathbb N$:
$$
\begin{cases}
0 \leq u_n \leq 3 \\
0 \leq v_n \leq 3
\end{cases}
$$
However, now I have to show this:
$$
\begin{cases}
|u_{n+1}-1| \leq |v_n-2| \\
|v_{n+1}-2| \leq \frac{1}{2}|u_n-1|
\end{cases}
$$
I thought about showing it by induction but I didn't manage to do it that way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the first inequality. Notice that 
$$|u_{n+1}-1|\le |v_n-2|\\\Leftrightarrow |\sqrt{3-v_n}-1|\le|v_n-2|\\\Leftrightarrow|\sqrt{3-v_n}-1|\le |3-v_n-1|\\\Leftrightarrow |\sqrt{3-v_n}-1|\le|(\sqrt{3-v_n})^2-1|\\\Leftrightarrow |\sqrt{3-v_n}-1|\le |\sqrt{3-v_n}+1|\cdot |\sqrt{3-v_n}-1|\\\Leftrightarrow 1\le |\sqrt{3-v_n}+1|,$$
which is obviously true.

For the second, notice that 
$$2|v_{n+1}-2|\le |u_n-1|\\\Leftrightarrow 2|\sqrt{3+u_n}-2|\le |u_n-1|\\\Leftrightarrow 2|\sqrt{3+u_n}-2|\le|(\sqrt{3+u_n})^2-4|\\\Leftrightarrow 2|\sqrt{3+u_n}-2|\le |\sqrt{3+u_n}+2|\cdot |\sqrt{3+u_n}-2|\\\Leftrightarrow 2\le |\sqrt{3+u_n}+2|,$$
which is once again true.

Comment: I apologize, I did a mistake which I fixed by editing now

Comment: $u_{n+1}$ is defined using $v_n$ and $v_{n+1}$ is defined using $u_n$

Comment: Also I don't see why showing that $-3 \leq u_n \leq 3$ solves my problem.

Comment: @QuentinJanuel That's roughly the same exercise. Given that $u_n,v_n\in [0,3]$, then $u_{n+1}=\sqrt{3-v_n}\in [0,\sqrt 3]\subseteq [0,3]$ and the same for $v_{n+1}$. Given that $u_0,v_0\in [0,3]$, then you are done.

Comment: I beg your pardon once more but I'm afraid you misunderstood what I had to show

Comment: I already showed that $u_n, v_n \in [0, 3]$. Now my issue is with the inequality that follows in my post.

Comment: @QuentinJanuel Sorry I failed to get your problem. But now I get it. The answer has been updated.

Comment: Thank you very much. I finally managed to find it though but thanks a ton anyway!